# Number theory The Quadratic Reciprocity

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Let $p$ be an odd prime $p > 3$. What is $\dfrac{-2}{p}$?

I need some help with this problem

Comment: If this is from an assignment, probably $(2/p)$ was already done in class, and you know about $(-1/p)$. You can combine these two pieces of knowledge to get to $(-2/p)$.

Answer (score 4):

This is a special case that is proved separately.

In the two cases $$p \equiv 1,3 \pmod 8, \; \; \; (-2 | p) = 1.$$

In the two cases $$p \equiv 5,7 \pmod 8, \; \; \; (-2 | p) = -1.$$

This has a concrete shape: whenever 
$$p \equiv 1,3 \pmod 8, \; \; \exists \; u,v \in \mathbb Z : u^2 + 2 v^2 = p.$$ 
These give the basic examples for  alternate Pythagorean triples,
$$  (u^2 - 2 v^2)^2 + 2 (2 uv)^2 = p^2.   $$

Then again, whenever 
$p \equiv 5,7 \pmod 8,$ if
$$  x^2 + 2 y^2 \equiv 0 \pmod p, \; \mbox{then} \; x,y \equiv 0 \pmod p, \; \mbox{and} \;  x^2 + 2 y^2 \equiv 0 \pmod {p^2}. $$